# Each of next() and list() iterates over generator with mutable object differently

Tags: python

```
def generator(dct):
    for i in range(3):
        dct['a'] = i
        yield dct

g = generator({'a': None})
next(g) # -> {'a': 0}
next(g) # -> {'a': 1}
next(g) # -> {'a': 2}

g = generator({'a': None})
list(g) # -> [{'a': 2}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 2}]
```

`next` iterates generator as I expected. However, `list` iterates unexpectedly. I think it should return `[{'a': 0}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]` since `next` iterates without problem.

I wonder what makes this difference.

(my environment: python 3.6.5, conda 4.5.4, Windows)

Comment: Both of these results are expected.  You are changing `dict` (which you shouldn't use as a variable name btw), but in the first case you are viewing the intermediate results

Comment: Try yielding `dict.copy()` and you'll see the difference

Comment: You shouldn't name a `dict` "`dict`".

Comment: You really shouldn't write generators with side effects. Generators generate stuff; they shouldn't modify stuff.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: that's not generally true anymore. Coroutines are built on top of generators. Coroutines routinely have side effects.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: and using generators to communicate about a process that has side effects is very effective too. Your generalisation doesn't hold, sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure what "communicate about a process that has side effects" means; could you elaborate?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: say, a generator that downloads an image and yields progress information every step. Or writes data you send to it with `generator.send()` and yields stats on that process. Generators are a general concept of a process that can be suspended, not just a sequence factory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `generator()` generator always yields the *same* `dict` object, just with modifications made to it between calls.  If you were to, say, change the first `next(g)` to `x = next(g)` and then inspect `x` before and after calling `next(g)` again, you would see the value of `x` change across calls, because `generator()` is always modifying & yielding the same `dict` object.

Answer (score 3):

They iterate over the iterator identically, but you're checking in at different points.  Because `dict`s are mutable, and you always `yield` the same `dict`, you should expect everything you yield to be identical.  In your first example, you are looking at the `dict` as it is changing.  Instead consider

```
g = generator({'a': None})

a = next(g)
b = next(g)
c = next(g)

print(a, b, c)
# {'a': 2} {'a': 2} {'a': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at *intermediate print results*. You are modifying a single dictionary, and sharing references to it. You can see the intermediary steps, but that doesn't mean the result is different.

Store a reference to the object returned from `next()` and they'll all be the same:

```
g = generator({'a': None})
first = next(g)
second = next(g)
third = next(g)
print(first, second, third) # -> {'a': 2}  {'a': 2}  {'a': 2}
```

`first`, `second` and `third` are all references to the *same object*:

```
>>> first is second and second is third
True
```

You'd see the same thing if you did this in a regular `for` loop:

```
>>> results = []
>>> d = {'a': None}
>>> for i in range(3):
...     d['a'] = i
...     print(d)
...     results.append(d)
...
{'a': 0}
{'a': 1}
{'a': 2}
>>> print(results)
[{'a': 2}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 2}]
>>> all(d is elem for elem in results)  # all references in results are the same object
True
```

The loop prints the dictionary object as it changes each step. The `results` list contains 3 references to the same object, and each shows the same state once printed at the end.